# chrome.runtime.sendMessage on console not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, gopherjs

I have a chrome extension and I am trying to send values from websites to the extension with chrome.runtime.sendMessage(). The thing is I have to do this from Go side using Gopher.js. I built a similar example here https://gopherjs.github.io/playground/#/-9C5IHFkMN

But, when I try to send the message nothing happens on the extension side, namely the listener in background.js is not triggered (with or without the sendResponse). I see the same effect when I run the chrome.runtime.sendMessage on the console with the following. When I execute a content script that sends a message, then the background listener is triggered. I am wondering what I am doing wrong.

This is what I run on the console:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(extension_id, "hello")
```

This is the background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log("new message", request);
    sendResponse({ message: "Background has received that message ?" });
});
```

This is the Manifest.json in the extension:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Name",
    "description": "This is a chrome extension",
    "version": "1.0",


    "background": {
        "scripts" : ["wasm_exec.js", "background.js" ],
        "persistent": true,
        "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
    },
    "permissions": [
      "tabs", 
      "background", 
      "<all_urls>", 
      "activeTab",
      "webRequest",
      "webRequestBlocking",
      "contentSettings",
      "browsingData",
      "storage"
    ],
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://rawgit.com/caolan/async/master/dist/async.min.js https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js  ;  object-src 'self'; "
  }
```

Comment: See [Sending messages from web pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage).

Comment: Thanks for your message, I am seeing that I had to define "externally_connectable" and it has to be at least second level domain. Is it applied for other type of permissions like localStorage? I mean is there any database-like or key-value like mechanism that I can communicate with any website?

Comment: Accessing any site storage can be performed directly in a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).